# Converting HTML into special characters for saving on SQL

Tags: php, html

My problem is. I have an input on HTML code which receives the users text. That could be

```
just an "example" of an entry (on the input);
```

So, I need to convert that special caracters ", (, ), ', ' to the special codes
[html special codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5k35.png)

I'm trying to use php function str_replace to swap the caracters with the code, but when I do that the new string keep the caracters instead of the code. Is there any way to convert those caracters to use them on a sql insert/update without errors?

I hope that edit help a little.
Sorry about my english.

Comment: What you need for saving in SQL is __prepared statements__ and not the useless stuff you're trying right now.

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why not simply *escape* the characters with \ when outputting them in PHP? It's unusual to want to insert quotes into a database. I agree that this seems like an XY problem.

Comment: I edited that. I'll read about that injection u_mulder. Thank you.